# Delete object stored in a vector, but dont resize the vector after

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a `std::vector` and I want to remove an object from it, but dont want it to be resized. Just empty so I can fill it in that exact position again.

```
std::vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(6);
vec.push_back(-17);
vec.push_back(12);

vec.erase(vec.begin() + 1);
```

so remove -17, but then be able to fill position 1 with something else.

Comment: You can always reassign the elements. What’s the issue? Seems like an X/Y question.

Comment: [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think [std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) will somewhat do what you want. its the front-side of the remove/erase idiom, and will not resize your container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*I want to remove an object from it, but dont want it to be resized. Just empty so I can fill it in that exact position again"*

Do not erase the old element, but instead, at the moment you would insert "new" value at exact position, just rewrite the old element with new one:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(6);
...
vec[1] = 4;  // rewrites 2nd element with value 4
```

Consider implementing a *NULL object* design pattern, which is based on constructing a "null" object with explicitly marked state / flag to "invalid" and a simple getter `bool isValid()`. You could also create a simple method that would release the objects resources and mark it as invalid, let's say `dispose()` or `destroy()`.

You might also consider using other type of container, such as `std::list`, which would solve your problems with inserting / deleting at specific position, however rapidly slow down traversal through elements.

Comment: is there a way to do it where I dont fill it immediately? I think I will need to fill it later. i.e enemies on a screen. `vec.clear()`?

Comment: or I could fill it with some empty object and then when I am ready to re-assign, just loop through for positions with an empty object and make the assignment then

Answer (score 0):

`vec.erase(vec.begin() + 1)` erases the -17, filling the gap by moving later elements. This, and inserting an element at the position again has linear performance w.r.t. the number of elements that follow the position.

If you have an integer that you do not use for any other purpose, you can use that as kind of a `NAN` for integers. In that case, `vec[1] = NAN` will sort of erase the element at index 1 and leave a gap for later use.

If neither of these is acceptable, use a different data structure, such as a list or a hash map.

Comment: NAN is a good idea. my actual vector doesn't contain an int, but an object. I could just fill the position with an empty object with a unique ID and later loop through and fill positions with have an id of my unique scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can always insert at specific position

```
void insert_at(std::vector<int> &v, size_t pos, int val)
{
  //Could make it as template for other vector of objects
   auto it =v.begin();

   if(pos < v.size())
   {
     std::advance(it, pos);

      v.insert(it,val);
   }
   //This function may need some other checks too
} 

vec.erase(vec.begin() + 1)
//...
insert_at(vec,1,100);
```

Comment: However, from the OPs description it sounds like he wants to keep using his vector ignoring some specific (deleted) elements so that indices of other elements stay unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<Obj*> Objects;
Objects.push_back(new Obj);
Objects.push_back(new Obj);

delete Objects[0];
Objects[0] = new Obj;
delete Objects[1];
Objects[1] = new Obj;

for (Obj* it : Objects)
{
    delete it;
}
```

Just simply replacing the value at the position should suffice..